# Setting up MySQL master-slave replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

I am trying to setup master-slave replication on MySQL 5.6.

When I update my database in the master, the change is not reflected on the slave. When I show the process list on the slave it shows this message:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| Id | User        | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State                                                                       | Info             |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|  1 | system user |           | NULL | Connect | 6440 | Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it | NULL             |
|  2 | system user |           | NULL | Connect | 5730 | Waiting for master to send event                                            | NULL             |
| 42 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL                                                                        | show processlist |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share the output of `show slave status\G` (as such it appears connected) and also output of `my.cnf` of master/slave. Mainly you need to worry about server-ids, replication filters (replicate-to-db/table etc) See also the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-howto.html). Step by step blog if  you need to review: http://fromdual.com/how_to_setup_mysql_master-slave_replication

Answer (score 0):

See the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html) or a [Step by step replication setup blog](http://fromdual.com/how_to_setup_mysql_master-slave_replication) if you need to review.

If these doesn't help please share the output of `show slave status\G` (as such it appears connected) and also output of `my.cnf` of master/slave. 
Mainly you need to worry about server-ids, replication filters (replicate-to-db/table etc)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. i forget to put the replicate-do-db in the slave's my.cnf file. now its working fine .

Comment: Glad to hear that...

Answer (score 0):

This command may not have run properly on slave while configuring its master

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='xx.xx.xx.xx', MASTER_USER='replication', MASTER_PASSWORD='xxxxxxxxxxx', MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.00xxxx', MASTER_LOG_POS=xxx
```